# How to login to Audible.com subsidiary of Amazon using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to scrape Audible websites using Python Beautiful Soup. There are some data that I cannot access unless I log into my Audible account. It is a subsidiary of Amazon.com. I have been unsuccessful. I just want to login using Python and scrape the html.

I have tried various code such as this [How to login to Amazon using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597061/how-to-login-to-amazon-using-beautifulsoup). One would think that simply substituting my credentials in this code would work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this can no longer be simply automated in Python. This is as far as i could get with **Audible AU**. POST requires bunch of headers, which most of them can be extracted, except for `metadata1` (more on that at the bottom):

```py
"""load packages"""
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs

"""define URL where login form is located"""
site = "https://www.audible.com.au/signin"

"""initiate session"""
session = requests.Session()

"""define session headers"""
session.headers = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,cs;q=0.8",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36",
    "metadata1": "",
}

"""get login page"""
resp = session.get(site)
html = resp.text

"""extract clientContext from the login page"""
query = urlsplit(resp.url).query
params = parse_qs(query)
clientContext = params["clientContext"]
new_login_url = "https://www.amazon.com.au/ap/signin/" + str(clientContext[0])

"""get BeautifulSoup object of the html of the login page"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

"""scrape login page to get all the needed inputs required for login"""
data = {}
form = soup.find("form", {"name": "signIn"})
for field in form.find_all("input"):
    try:
        data[field["name"]] = field["value"]
    except:
        pass

"""add username and password to the data for post request"""
data[u"email"] = "EMAIL"
data[u"password"] = "PASSWORD"

"""display: redirect URL, appActionToken, appAction, siteState, openid.return_to, prevRID, workflowState, create, email, password"""
print(new_login_url, data)

"""submit post request with username / password and other needed info"""
post_resp = session.post(new_login_url, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_resp.content, "lxml")

"""check the captcha"""
warning = post_soup.find("div", id="auth-warning-message-box")
if warning:
    print("Warning:", warning)
else: print(post_soup)

session.close()
```

Add your e-mail address and password on lines `48`, `49`. Also log in with your browser and inspect the traffic to see what is `metadata1` on your computer and add it on line `22`. If you're lucky and you will not get detected as bot, you will get in, otherwise you will get captcha image.

`metadata1` is a massive payload in base64 which consist data collected by your browser which uniquely identifies you and differentiates you from the bots (mouse-clicks, delay in typing, page script, browser information & compatibility & extensions, flash version, user agent, script performance, hardware - GPU, local storage, canvas size, etc ...)

Comment: I couldn't find the metadata in the network console. Also, I recently enabled Timed One Time Passwords. I ran into that and not captcha. Still, your script got me closer than anything else.