# Using BeautifulSoup where authentication is required

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lan, intranet

I am scraping LAN data using BeautifulSoup4 and Python requests for a company project. Since the site has a login interface, I am not authorized to access the data. The login interface is a pop-up that doesn't allow me to access the page source or inspect the page elements without log in. the error I get is this-

**Access Error: Unauthorized
Access to this document requires a User ID**

[This is a screen-shot of the pop-up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCM9e.png) (The blackened part is sensitive information). It has not information about the html tags at all, hence I cannot auto-login via python.

I have tried requests_ntlm, selenium, python requests and even ParseHub but it  did not work. I have been stuck in this phase for a month now! Please, any help would be appreciated.

Below is my initial code:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("www.amazon.in")
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
print r.content
r = requests.get("www.amazon.in",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('user_name','passwd'))
print r.content*

s_data = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")*
print s_data.content
```

Error:
    Document Error: Unauthorized

### Access Error: Unauthorized

Access to this document requires a User ID

This is the error I get when BeautifulSoup tries to access the data after I have **manually logged into** the site.

Comment: (unable-to-log-in-to-amazon-using-python) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488023/unable-to-log-in-to-amazon-using-python]

Comment: Clarification: The website url I provided is just a sample. I am not allowed to disclose the real one since its a private site.

Comment: Using `urllib` and `requests` alone won't help much where logins are required. Use `requests.Session`. If you're unfamiliar with it, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/. Also, open the developer's tab in your browser and study the network window to see what requests are sent by the browser with what query strings and headers. Using `User-Agent` alone won't suffice in some cases. You'll have to provide a bit more information for us to help further. Perhaps, consider posting the contents of network tab and mask the sensitive information by replacing them with fake one.

Comment: Also, BeautifulSoup has nothing to do with the problem you're facing. So consider editing your post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using mechanise?

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cook = cookielib.CookieJar()
req = mechanize.Browser()
req.set_cookiejar(cook)


req.open("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1")

req.select_form(nr=0)
req.form['username'] = 'username'
req.form['password'] = 'password.'
req.submit()

print req.response().read()
```

**EDIT**

If you come up against robots.txt issues and you have permission to circumvent this then take a look at this answer for techniques to do this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/13303773#13303773)

Comment: I tried it. The error I got is this-  mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Comment: Hmm ok well if you plan to monetise your work then you have problems scraping this site. How does their robots.txt read?

Comment: I am not going to monetize this site. It is for inter-organizational use only. I do not have access to the robots.txt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using BeautifulSoup and requests on Python 3.x, just use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('URL', auth=('USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```