# Download files from CloudFront via Python with basic Username and Password

Tags: python, amazon-s3, download, python-requests, amazon-cloudfront

I was given a urls to files in CloudFront. I can access the files that I need via Chrome. Whenever I enter the url, it downloads automatically. I only enter username and password the first time to get the files (in the browser).

The url looks something like this: https://abcsdjdfhdsk.cloudfront.net/somefolderhere/**anumberishere**/some_really_long_file_identifer

My question is, how do I structure a requests.get request to download the files **automatically**. Whenever I access new files (swapping out the last part of the url, the really long id), it downloads automatically, but only in Chrome. If I clear my history and cache and try it again, I get prompted for username and password. I do not have anything else.

If I try requests.get(urlhere), then I always get a 401 error.

I can see in the web traffic that it is Amazon S3
How can I automate this with python? Do I need something more?

**fixed with the following code**

import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

requests.get(reallylongurl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), headers = headers)

Comment: mind to post a link ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987241/using-beautifulsoup-where-authentication-is-required

Answer (score 0):

**fixed with the following code**

import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

requests.get(reallylongurl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), headers = headers)